ORDS connection pool vs ORACLE APEX Static files
forgive me as I am a kind of learning APEX architecture.
We have ORDS with Gateway user and APEX setup. When we are using only one connection pool (APEX_PUBLIC_USER)by default, APEX app can be accessed though https://hostname/ords/f?p=100 and Static CSS/JS files works perfect.
We have a requirement to use different Gateway user (G_USER) and thus we added another connection pool Called '/G'.
After that connection pool is added,
the original https://hostname/ords/f?p=100 still works for APEX app.
However, https://hostname/ords/G/f?p=100 for new Gateway use G_USER giving us 404 data file not founds for CSS/JS file we have on Workspace.
When I look at the exact URL for Static files, it is looking at https://hostname/ords/G/..../TEST.CSS with extra /G.
Question1:Is there any links between ORDS connection pool and APEX static files?
Question2:Is this related to ORDS or APEX?
Quesiton3:It does seems like it is looking for Static files under /G/... Is there any configuration at APEX we can do to point it to Original URL just by using #WORKSPACE_FILE#TEST.CSS?
I am a kind of stuck and any recommendation/suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot for the answer!
tried replacing #WORKSPACE_FILE# by Original working url, it works but I feel like it is no the right way to do.

I would post this question in the oracle forum https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/apex

are you using a really old ords? b/c new ords has everything, including apex, run through ords_public_user - and note your apex static content can also be setup to use the apex content delivery network (CDN) vs relying on it being in ords .. also +1 to the asking in the oracle forums

@KoenLostrie Thanks you.  I posted the question at Oracle Forum.

@thatjeffsmith Thanks you. I am using ORDS version 22.3.

ok in that version of ords, when you set it up for apex, the pool is configured for ords_public_user
